# Failing to Satisfy SDK constraints in an imported Dart Package

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to import a package I just uploaded, but I get the below error.

**Error:**

```
packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in sickw_flutter...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.0.0-dev.55.0.flutter-43635d3372.

Because sickw_flutter depends on imei_validator any which requires SDK version >=0.8.7 <=2.0.0-dev.55.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've already read and followed [the documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec#sdk-constraints) for uploading my package, but I can't seem to see the reason for the error.

**Links:**

[pub.dartlang.org](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/imei_validator)

[Github](https://github.com/thinkdigitalrepair/imei_validator)

Comment: I'd create a bug report for imei_validator to losen SDK constraints.

Comment: Have you updated the pubspec of sickw_flutter to ensure it's requiring at least 0.1.1?

Comment: I wrote the package myself, @GünterZöchbauer. How do I loosen them? I'd rather not have any upper bound on my constraints. I tried adding a higher, unreleased version, but it didn't fix it. 
And Yes, for the version I'm using,  my pubspec says `dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  imei_validator: any`


Also, when publishing, the pub warns: _Published packages should have an upper bound constraint on the Dart SDK (typically this should restrict to less than the next major version to guard against breaking changes)._

Comment: Also, do you know of a way to test this package out locally so I don't have to upload new versions each time I need to test a change?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I changed the upper bound to 3.0.0 and it seems to work now, thank you. I guess I didn't go far enough

Comment: If you publish it, it should be `<2.0.0` until Dart 2 is released and then you can release it with `">=2.0.0<3.0.0"`

Comment: But since I myself am already using a version greater than 2.0, I'll be restricting myself...